# placing three android linear layouts

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to place 3 linear layouts on same page of android.
Two besides each other and the other one below the two.
The view is in landscape mode and it should cover the whole screen.
How to do that in xml file?

I am not being able to post my code. Seems like its not working

Comment: Attention, you forget to post the code :)

Answer (score 2):

You will do something like this

```
<LL orientation=vertical android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LL orientation:horizontal>
    <LL><!-- First of the two who are beside--></LL>
    <LL><!-- Second of the two who are beside--></LL>
</LL>
<LL>
</LL>
</LL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use RelativeLayout for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
    <LinearLayout  
       android:id="@+id/layoutLeftTop"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">  
    <!-- Content of the first layout -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout  
       android:id="@+id/layoutRightTop"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"> 
    <!-- Content of the second layout -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout  
       android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >  
    <!-- Content of the third layout at bottom -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```